Reference a file with no extension in Doxygen
I want to reference a LICENSE file in my Doxygen documentation with @ref to avoid constantly rewriting a long copyright section each time I want to mention copyright. I understand I could write it all into an alias and use that instead, but I would like to avoid that. I'm assuming I can use FILE_PATTERNS but haven't been able to figure it out.
My Doxyfile: https://pastebin.com/kRKjanKc
Project file structure:
Project-Root/
--- Dir-to-document/
------ build/
------ config/
--------- files.c
--------- files.h
------ docs/
--------- Doxyfile
--------- misc.dox
--------- SYMLINK-TO-README
--------- SYMLINK-TO-LICENSE
------ resources/
------ scripts/
------ themes/
--------- files.c
--------- files.h
------ files.c
------ files.h
--- Dir-not-documented-1/
--- Dir-not-documented-2/
--- LICENSE
--- README

scripts/, resources/, and build/ are all excluded, as well as a few config files.
Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm just learning Doxygen. If I missed something, feel free to ask for it in the comments.

Which version of doxygen are you using? Did you see the no_extension of the no_extensions setting (see your Doxyfile or https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_extension_mapping): Note: For files without extension you can use no_extension as a placeholder. Note best is always to place the content of the setting file in the question in the formof the result of doxygen -x Doxyfile).

1.11.0, and yes I did see no_extension, however I believe that my issue is in getting doxygen to pickup the file as one it should document or include, not necessarily that it is using the parser. Edit: It may just be me not using it correctly, but I couldn't get it to work using no_extension, I did try.

In your Doxyfile, which has to be inside the question in the form of the result of doxygen -x Doxyfle) I don't see the EXTENSION_MAPPING with the setting for no_extension please try EXTENSION_MAPPING = no_extension=md

Yeah, tried that, sadly to no effect. Even tried testing that the directory the license is in is being included and it is, adding source files there, they are properly documented. So it can see the LICENSE file but does not seem to allow me to document it, even with the above mentioned mapping.

Adding a little more here, because I realize my last statement is vague, I managed to get Doxygen to show LICENSE in the list of files, but am unable to either reference or document it. I am using */LICENSE in FILE_PATTERNS to get it to show up, as nothing using no_extension has done anything.

Please add a small complete example to this issue or start a discussion at https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/discussions (with a small complete example).
